# assassin creed brotherhood : mac requirement

Tags: graphics, games

I have a early 2011 Macbook pro with graphic card as Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB, will Assassin creed : brotherhood run on this Mac version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will, but the graphics card is not supported by the game manufacturer.